# dynamic web priject is missing on eclipse version 2021-09

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web, dynamic

I download Eclipse version 2021.09, and i don't have Dynamic Web project option.
I tried to install it with Help => install new software => select Web,XML, JavaEE ... and restart Eclipse.
After restart Eclipse, i still don't hava web dynamic project option.

How can i set this option ?

Comment: Why are you using 2021-09 which is 5 releases old? It is always recommended that you use the current release (2022-12 currently)

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r , **Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers** (Windows x86_64 , macOS x86_64 | AArch64 , Linux x86_64 | AArch64  )

Comment: 2021.09 is a version number, but it doesn't convey what's in the particular package, which can vary: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare